No files found for remoteEntry chunk
I have the following module federation configuration in my webpack.config.json
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'my-app',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './MyApp': './src/app/App.tsx',
      },
}),


When I try to serve the application I get the following error and the remote entry is not configured:
HookWebpackError: [ Module Federation Manifest Plugin ]: no files found for remoteEntry chunk
However, I cannot find the source of the issue.
Here the full configuration and the project structure
webpack.config.ts
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ModuleFederationPlugin =
  require('@module-federation/enhanced').ModuleFederationPlugin;
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.tsx',
  target: 'web',
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    port: 4201,
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'async',
    },
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: 'auto',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../../dist/apps/my-app'),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'my-app',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './MyApp': './src/app/App.tsx',
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};

App.tsx
export const MyApp = () => {
  return <div data-testid="MAIN_PAGE">Info plus Page</div>;
};



In this scenario the hypen was causing the issue. Renaming the package from my-package to my_package solved the problem.

They should really add this check to the tool. So many people getting burned by a simple check.
